# null is not an object(evaluating 'blob.data') fetch react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to JS and im trying to use Fetch to consume services in a react mobile app.
I want to somehow catch the error i get from not having a connection or access to the server, but instead of catching the error, the app crashes with **null is not an object(evaluating 'blob.data')**

```
import GlobalURL from './Url';

export const getMailAvailability = async (mail) => {
    let url = GlobalURL +  mail;
    await fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {},
    })
        .then(async (data) => {
            return await data.json();
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log("error")
            console.log(error)
        })
}
```

another thing to have in mind, if the app does have access to the internet or access to the server, it works perfectly.

Comment: in your first `then` block, that argument is not `data` it's the HTTP response object. Im guessing there is a good chance that you do not actually have a JSON response meaning you can't call `.json()` on it. make sure your content-application header is set correctly and examine the response

Comment: The `async/await` facility was introduced into the language so that you don't have to code `.then()` and `.catch()` handlers. You can instead just write code that *looks* like plain old synchronous code. It isn't, in reality, but it avoids the mess of callbacks

Comment: The problem is your use of `async/await` and the fluent methods like `then` and `catch` on the `Promise`. 

Use one or the other, especially in such a small method, but not both without a very good reason.

Comment: i didn't knew that! thanks for the tip, i will have that in mind the next time. Changing that didn't solve my issue though, i managed to make it work downloading Axios and using it accordingly. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the fetch errors with this function.

```
import GlobalURL from './Url';

function handleFetchErrors (response) {
  if (!response.ok) throw Error(response.statusText)
  return response
}

export const getMailAvailability = async (mail) => {
    let url = GlobalURL +  mail;
    return fetch(url, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {},
    })
    .then(res => handleFetchErrors(res))
    .then(data =>  data.json())
    .catch((error) => console.log("error ", error))
}
```

Comment: thanks for the replay! this didn't solve my issue though... when i turn off my backend and try to call this method, the error still stands :(